# Gnu Sed (on Gnu/Linux) to find match + "anything" and replacing it

Tags: sed, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use sed to find matching string on a line in a file on nth match.
I want to use expression to mach `num` and "anything" after on that line and replace it with `num x`.

example file:

```
START
num 1
num 1
num 1
num n
END
```

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/num .*/num x/1' example
```

outputs:

```
START
num x
```

---

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/num 1/num x/1' example
```

outputs:

```
START
num x
num 1
num 1
num n
END
```

Im tyring to use the `.*` expression to match anything after `num` and replace it with 
`num x`
but my result leaves the end of the file out.
Replacing the `.*` expression with the actual full string on that line gives the desired result, but it must be possible that there is "anything" following characters on that line.

Comment: It's unclear what your expected output should look like. Please [edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was not exactly right.

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\nnum[^\n]*/\nnum x/4' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is the best tool for doing s/old/new on individual lines, for anything else just use awk;

```
$ awk -v n=4 '/num/ && ((++c) == n){$0="num x"} {print}' file
START
num 1
num 1
num 1
num x
END
```